# How to retrieve data from table A using data from table B in my autosuggest script?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, autosuggest

I am learning php and mysql and have now encountered a problem.

I am using a autosuggestion php/javascript script that, out of the box, basicly takes user input in a html form, uses javascript to send the user input to my php file where it searches through the database with the "LIKE" query command, and then returnes a html  list with list items containing the "name" data found by the query.

**Now to my question:** I have two tables in my database, wp_terms and wp_term_taxonomy (see illustraton bellow). Currently, the query searches through all entries in the "wp_terms" table and selects the "name" entry. But i wish to add a kind of filter. I wish to only get the names of the entries which have the integer "2" as "parent".

I think the aproach to this would be searching through "wp_term_taxonomy", store the "term_id"'s of the entries with the integer "2" as parent. Then have another query which goes through the "wp_terms" table and outputs the "names" of the stored "term_id's".

I don't know if this would be the correct approach or not. I have tried for days now, without success and would really appreciate some help.

**Database tables illustration:**
[image]

**My autosuggest.php code. This is were the magic happens:**

```
<?php
   $db_host = 'localhost';
   $db_username = 'user';
   $db_password = 'passw';
   $db_name = 'db';

   $db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username ,$db_password, $db_name);

    if(!$db) {

        echo 'Could not connect to the database.';
    } else {

        if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
            $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

            if(strlen($queryString) >0) {

                $query = $db->query("SELECT name FROM wp_terms WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");

                if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
                    if($query) {
                    echo '<ul>';
                        while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                            echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->name).'\');">'.$result->name.'</li>';
                        }       
                    echo '</ul>';

                    } else {
                        echo 'OOPS we had a problem :(';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<ul>';
                    echo '<span style="color:#0196E3";>'.$queryString.'</span> no matches found.';
                    echo '</ul>';
                }   
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        } else {
            echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I edited your post to contain the image you were hyperlinking to before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to accomplish this.

```
SELECT `wp_terms`.`name`
FROM `wp_terms`
INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy`
ON `wp_terms`.`term_id`=`wp_term_taxonomy`.`term_id`
AND `wp_term_taxonomy`.`parent`=2
WHERE `wp_terms`.`name` LIKE '$queryString%'
LIMIT 10
```

[Take a look here for visual explanations of how joins work.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Basically, when you do a join, you are combining both tables based on which join you are using.  This query inner joins the tables based on `term_id`, and ensures you will only return rows where `parent` is equal to 2.

By the way, you really should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).  MySQLi will [disappoint you in the long run](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/), and I believe its use may even be deprecated.

Comment: @user1991083 Glad I could help!  Thanks for accepting my answer - I'd appreciate an upvote, too, if you don't mind.  ;)

Comment: I don't have the required 15 reputation to cast a vote :/ I will come back at a later time and give you an upvote if I remember it :) Anyway, thanks again.